# Moving foward to the face direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have player charactor which has face(head) and body.

```
Player - Head
       - Body
```

Currently my source code attached to the `player` is like this,

```
public void moveForward(){
    Debug.Log("move forward");
    speed = 40;
    Debug.Log("Head Rotation y:" + head.transform.localEulerAngles.y); // For example it shows 30
    float y_rotation = head.transform.localEulerAngles.y;
    this.transform.Translate(0,0,speed/50);// It goes to the player direction, how can I move forward to the face direction???
}
```

This function makes character move forward, but it comes to the player direction.

I would like to move forward to the face direction, How can I make this??

---

Updated article

```
public void moveForward(){
    Debug.Log("move forward");
    speed = 40;
   Debug.Log("head.transform.forward.x:"+ head.transform.forward.x);//1
    Debug.Log("head.transform.forward.y:"+ head.transform.forward.y);//0
    Debug.Log("head.transform.forward.z:"+ head.transform.forward.z);// -1.192093E-07

    Debug.Log("this.transform.forward.x:"+ this.transform.forward.x);0
    Debug.Log("this.transform.forward.y:"+ this.transform.forward.y);0
    Debug.Log("this.transform.forward.z:"+ this.transform.forward.z);1


//somehow this two do the same move,,
    this.transform.position += head.transform.forward * vz / 50f * Time.deltaTime;
    //this.transform.position += this.transform.forward * vz / 50f * Time.deltaTime;

}
```

Comment: So if the player has his face pointing at an incline to the floor it would also include the component that is parallel with gravity?

Comment: Also avoid using eular angles, unity uses quaternion internally and eular angles in some situations can be susceptible to gimble lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move in the direction the head is facing simply do

```
transform.position += head.transform.forward * speed / 50f * Time.deltaTime;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however, it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: @whitebear so what is intended and what happens instead?

Comment: It goes to the `Player` direction not to the head direction.

Comment: For example rotatiton of `Head` is (0,90,0) , and `Player` rotation kept as (0,0,0) It goes to the Player direction not head direction.

Comment: I checked what the `head.transform.forward`. it shows like this , `head.transform.forward.x = 1`, `head.transform.forward.y = 0`,`head.transform.forward.z = -1.192093E-07`,

Comment: yeah so it should go to the right ... is that not happening?

Comment: I updated the article some how The last two lines do the same move....     `this.transform.position += head.transform.forward * vz / 50f * Time.deltaTime;`
    `this.transform.position += this.transform.forward * vz / 50f * Time.deltaTime;` Both goes to the same direction, not face direction.

Comment: WOW it works. I have some logic error in other function, so your advice is completely right.